# Getting strange value when convert to float in C

Tags: c

I run below code in `TI C654X_0 MCU`, but always get strange result for `xval, yval, zval -> f, f, f` as given in the log. I run the same code in online C compiler, the result is correct. I cannot understand why this issue happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141592654

....
obj.x = 14690; obj.y = 14347; obj.z = 14607;

uint32_t patternCheck(detectedObj obj)
{
   uint32_t retVal = 0;
   int xyzQFormat = 7;

   if(obj.x != 0 && obj.y !=0 && obj.z!=0){   
    float xval = (float)abs(obj.x) / (1 << xyzQFormat);
    float yval = (float)abs(obj.y) / (1 << xyzQFormat);
    float zval = (float)abs(obj.z) / (1 << xyzQFormat);
    float objAdeg = (atan(xval / yval) * 180) / PI;
    float objEdeg = (atan(zval / yval) * 180) / PI;
    float objAdist = sqrt(xval*xval + yval*yval);
    float objEdist = sqrt(zval*zval + yval*yval);
    System_printf("%d, %d, %d, %2.6f, %2.6f, %2.6f, %d \n", obj.x, obj.y, obj.z, xval, yval, zval, xyzQFormat);
    retVal = 1;
   }

   return retVal;
}
```

log:

```
[C674X_0] 14690, 14347, 14607,  f,  f,  f, 7
```

Comment: Does pritnf() give you the same result?  In other words maybe your System_printf() doesn't float (double) :-)

Comment: Or has to be specifically enabled (to keep the code size down).

Comment: Please add to your question the compiler and its version. Optimally provide a link to its documentation, especially of the linker and standard library. However, you should have read this yourself...

Comment: The use of `System_printf()`is really primitive for TI. Maybe try to play with your stack-size. Best is to avoid it.

Comment: Can you remove the 3x "2.6" from the format specifier to see if you can, at least, get out a "simple floating point" number? Try simply "%f" to see if that gets you anywhere...

Comment: Well this is some exotic DSP. Why would it come with libs that has floating point support disabled? Surely it got a FPU. But it is generally good advise to never use any software written by TI.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, it is a very bad idea to mix fixed point, single precision floating point and double precision floating point in the same expression, aka "sloppy typing". Your code does this. Decide if you should use `float` or `double` then _only_ use that type for every single operand in the code. Otherwise you are actively begging for subtle implicit type conversion bugs to strike your code, over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible "workaround" (read "kludge") whereby you might be able to circumvent the problem. You could try "bypassing" the apparently handicapped `System_printf( )` with your own floating point to string conversion.

```
#include <math.h>

char *myFPfmt( char *dst, double val ) {
    int wh = floor( val );
    // Simplistic rounding and integer conversion
    int fr = floor( (val-wh)*1000*1000 + 0.5 );

    sprintf( dst, "%d.%06d", wh, fr ); // Can you get "leading 0s" at least?

    return dst;
}

int main() {
    double pi =  3.141592654;
    double eu =  2.718281828459;
    double da = 42.0042069;

    char buf[3][16]; // 3 values -> 3 buffers

    printf( "%2.6f  %2.6f  %2.6f\n", pi, eu, da );
    printf( "%s  %s  %s\n", myFPfmt( buf[0], pi ), myFPfmt( buf[1], eu ), myFPfmt( buf[2], da ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
3.141593  2.718282  42.004207
3.141593  2.718282  42.004207
```

EDIT:

With the basics out of the way (we hope), to acknowledge that numbers can be less than zero:

```
char *myFPfmt( char *dst, double val ) {
    char *sgn = val >= 0.0 ? "" : "-";
    val = fabs(val);
    int wh = floor( val );
    // Simplistic rounding and integer conversion
    int fr = floor( (val-wh)*1000*1000 + 0.5 );

    sprintf( dst, "%s%d.%06d", sgn, wh, fr ); // Can you get "leading 0s" at least?

    return dst;
}
```

And a test:

```
// try a single negative to test that, too
printf( "%s\n", myFPfmt( buf[0], (double)-13.0000789 ) );

/* Single test output
 * -13.000079
 */
```